Adding a non-solid ribbed surface to object
About 2,5 years ago, I asked this question (Adding a ribbed texture to object (eg. a vase)).
The answer provided by Blunder was exactly what I needed back then, and has actually helped me understand Blender a lot more. But I now need something slightly different, as Blunder's solution creates a solid ribbed surface, and I now need a non-solid ribbed surface.
Question: how do I add a non-solid ribbed surface to an object?
Blunder's answer adds a solid ribbed surface, like below:

However, I need a non-solid surface, like below. Basically just a line that goes around the object in a zig zag pattern. Is this do-able in Blender?



In this instance I would model it using curves. One of the ways of doing this would be using the array modifier and a curve modifier, to map one curve onto another.
First model the general profile of the 'rib' that you want replicated across the shape. We want this to be a curve for later, so you can do this as either a curve immediately, or model it as a few edges and then convert it to a curve when you're done.
You can do this by right-clicking on the mesh in object mode and selecting Convert To > Curve:

Then, add a separate BezierCircle, this will be the 'big shape' that your ribs will run along:

Going back to your rib curve, use an array modifier with a relative offset of 1 on the X axis to make a series of ribs in a line:

Finally add a curve modifier to the rib, selecting the 'big shape' as the Curve Object. In this case a Bezier circle.
Note: Here, depending on your file, you may need to try the different 'Deform Axis' till you find the one that works, in this example the default X worked.
You may need to move the rib object on different axis to get it to sit on the curve correctly as well.
Adjust the array count to fill the entire circle, clicking 'merge' and 'first and last copies' will make the shape join up at the ends.:

Finally select the rib object, we can add thickness and geometry to the curve in the curve properties tab, using the depth and extrude sliders:

You can end the modifier stack with a subdivision surface modifier for a nice finish:

I hope this helps!

Hey Ten,
That looks neat, exactly the style I'm after. Thanks for the clear instructions. I've followed them with a quickly drawn curve, and I'm getting a similar result (https://i.sstatic.net/LHEEprdr.png). However, my goal is to add the curve on the outside of an existing object, such as a vase (sample: https://i.sstatic.net/V0aLNTvt.png). The idea is to create something that looks more like this (https://i.sstatic.net/rE3YQEuk.png). For this sample I used the Displacement modifier, but that gives me a solid curve. I prefer this 'open' curve. Is it possible to add it to existing objects?

That's quite a difficult question, my initial response to that is to start thinking with geometry nodes, but if you don't know how to use them it may be quite the undertaking.
It's a bit of a long shot but this tutorial on making a cactus with geometry nodes may be useful, I'm sorry if I can't help you though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFnNpn5Ym4Y

Hi. You can try the Tissue add-on that comes with Blender. It can tessellate* objects (*make a pattern using identical shapes). It had two little flaws for organic-shaped vases in my tests. It requires a large amount of geometry and generates even more. And there can still be shading issues for organic curved-shaped objects. You can see the "flat-shaded" underlying geometry. But the object is smooth-shaded. Maybe I did something wrong. Here is the example: https://i.sstatic.net/7AKDObDe.jpg

Thanks for that suggestion Blunder. I'm still playing around with the add-on's functions, but seems like this definitely is going to fill my needs. Thanks once again!
